# How to pass column name as variable in sqlalchemy sum function

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
import sqlalchemy as db

engine = db.create_engine("")

connection = engine.connect()

metadata = db.MetaData()

table = db.Table('C_ODS_ST_EXPOSURE',metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine)
q = db.select([db.func.sum(table.columns.CLAIMORDER)])
```

I want CLAIMORDER which is a columnname in table C_ODS_ST_EXPOSURE as a variable

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to be able to do?

Comment: hi @snakecharmerb i have resolved the issue today night by using the below syntax       q=db.select([db.func.avg(getattr(columns,"{}".format(column_name)))]) where column_name is the parameter